# Get Kylo Feed ID from Ni-Fi processor

Tags: apache-nifi, kylo

I am trying to get the Feed ID from a processor inside the NiFi template implementation created by Kylo.

In other words, how can I know that feed ID the current processors reside in?

Tried using the GetFeedMetadata processor but it returns only the first feed details and not the current feed the processors belong to.

${feedJson:jsonPath('$.id')}

returns the first feed data not the current feed

Comment: What is the flow? Where do you get FlowFiles from? Is this JSON in the content or the attribute? Please provide more details

Comment: Hi Ben, Basically create a Feed in Kylo. This creates the template for the feed in NiFi. I want to get the Kylo Feed ID from within Ni-Fi. Usually the 'Initialize Feed Parameters' attribute update processor puts in the feed name and category and not the feed ID. We can use the API to get feed details using the name, but wanted to know if there is a direct approach.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Kylo, so I don't know what flow it generates.. I do know NiFi though, so could you screenshot the flow that's being generated?

Comment: Thanks Ben, this is Kylo specific. Kylo will have to add it while creating the NiFi processes. I found a workaround for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kylo has a 'Initialize Feed Parameters' update attribute processor, this puts a feed and category attribute. You can then call the /feedmgr/feeds/by-name/ API to get the Feed details.
Note that the feed name needed for this API is category.feedName, not simply the feed name. The documentation is not very clear on that.